# 3 level expandableListView in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm using three level expandable list view in my application, the problem is when i click on level 1 its open level 2 up to now its works fine, and if i click level 2, level 3 also opens and then i'm closing level 1, and now again opens level 1, level 2 opens but level 2 on Click does't work at all, its get freeze and **on Group Click Listener** not calls and also get View method not calls.

**Activity Class:**

```
 final ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.explist);
      if (!result.children.isEmpty()) {

      elv.setChildDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));

ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener grpLst = new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
       public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView eListView, View view, int groupPosition,   long id) {
                        return false;
                    }
                };
   ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener childLst = new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
                    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView eListView, View view, int groupPosition,
                            int childPosition, long id) {

                        return false ;
                    }               };

  ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener grpExpLst = new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
     @Override
       public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    }
                };
    adapter = new RootAdapter(EnrollTwo.this, result, grpLst, childLst, grpExpLst);
                elv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

            elv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    db.close();
                    if (lastExpandedGroupPosition != -1 && groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition) {
                        if(lastExpandedGroupPosition>groupPosition){
                        elv.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
                        }else{
                             elv.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
                }
            });
            elv.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {


                    return false;
                }
            });
```

**Level 1 Adapter**

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return root.children.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View     convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// second level list
return lsfirst[groupPosition].cls;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
return root.children.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
return root.children.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
ViewGroup parent) {

// first level

View layout = convertView;
final GroupViewHolder holder;
final Object item = (Object) getGroup(groupPosition);
if (layout == null) {

    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ite_root, parent, false);
    holder = new GroupViewHolder();
    holder.title = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.itemRootTitle);
    holder.iv=(ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.async);


    layout.setTag(holder);
} else {

    holder = (GroupViewHolder) layout.getTag();
}

holder.title.setText(item.title.trim());


    }
});
return layout;
}
private static class GroupViewHolder {
TextView title;
ImageView iv;

}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
 return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return true;
}
```

**Leve 2 Adapter**

```
   @Override
   public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
   return child.children.get(groupPosition).children.get(childPosition);
   }

 @Override
 public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
  return childPosition;
 }   


@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,    View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final Object item = (Object) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

final ChildViewHolder holder;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_child, parent, false);
    holder = new ChildViewHolder();
    holder.ply=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.play);
    holder.sdcard=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
    holder.sync=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sync);
    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemChildTitle);
    holder.title2=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemChildTitle2);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
 } else {
    holder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
 }
 return convertView;
 }
 @Override
  public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
 return child.children.get(groupPosition).children.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
return child.children.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
return child.children.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
return groupPosition;
}

// Second level
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View layout = convertView;
final ViewHolder holder;
final Object item = (Object) getGroup(groupPosition);

if (layout == null) 
{
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_parent, parent, false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.title = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.itemParentTitle);
    layout.setTag(holder);
}
else {

    holder = (ViewHolder) layout.getTag();
}
}
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return true;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
TextView title;
ImageView Giv;
}

private static class ChildViewHolder {
TextView title,title2;
ImageView ply,sdcard,sync;
}
```